# How can I get PHPMailer to send an email using Gmail's SMTP?

Tags: php, phpmailer, windows-server-2012-r2

I've installed PHPMailer onto Windows Server 2012 R2 (using IIS) and I'm trying to use it to send an email, here is my code:

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                        // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                               // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mailer->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';        // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                        // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'MyPassword';                // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                     // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                             // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'Martin');
$mail->addAddress('anotheraddress@emaildomain.co.uk', 'Hello');   // Add a recipient
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');      // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('anotheraddress@midlandairexpress.co.uk', 'Hello');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                    // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent';
}

?>
```

As you can see I've enabled debug output andwhen I try to run this I get:

```
     2017-05-07 20:36:28    Connection: opening to localhost:587, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2017-05-07 20:36:30    Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to localhost:587 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ) [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\email\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php line 292] 2017-05-07 20:36:30 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061) 2017-05-07 20:36:30    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I've installed PHP [screenshot of info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yElB8.jpg)

I've tried:
1. Looking through the GitHub documentation
2. Specifying the protocol before the name of the SMTP server (line 10)
3. Checking the SMTP info against Google's Support page
4. Checking the credentials of my email address (send from)

The PHPMailer folder is located within a folder on the server called **email**

```
 (Path to PHPMailerAutoload.php)
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\email\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoLoad.php
```

I'm fairly new to PHP but I have a basic understanding of how it works.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `$mailer->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';` should be `$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';` ?  Looks like maybe a typo so it's trying to connect to localhost:587

Comment: Drew spotted your problem, but I'd recommend starting with [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), which doesn't have this problem in the first place!

Comment: Thankyou drew010 and Synchro